# Python command handling

Tags: python, if-statement, input

Basically I've created a command-line python menu for fun and practice. The script has many fun features and commands, but the center of it is the actual command line that checks to see if the string entered corresponds to an option and executes it. I'm using if and elif to check the command, which has its downsides.

```
elif cmdprompt == '--help':
    print("\n"
    self.help()
```

The code above will take the user's input and if it is '--help' then it will run that function. However, if the user entered a string with any spaces, then it would be recognized as an invalid option. Using "or" seems to be inefficient, and it breaks my code if I use it with a lot of elifs. Is there any way I could make this command handling more flexible? Perhaps something that would just check to make sure that the user enter "--help" with any amount of spaces at the end.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: Use `string.trim()` to remove spaces at the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: @Polikdir He's doing a menu, not processing CLI arguments.

Comment: @Polikdir To have every single function require their own args it would be too much of a pain

Comment: `import sys; if sys.argv[1].strip() == '--help': ...`

Comment: Either way doing it without a function for every functionality would be considered bad stye IMO. But whatever you decide :) this is a good practice.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will eliminate the whitespace:

```
elif cmdprompt.strip() == '--help':
```

Alternately you can do this:

```
elif '--help' in cmdprompt:
```

But note that would match anything that contained `--help`, not just extra whitespace.